# Pycharm shows no problems but wont give any output

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I'm trying to make a script that takes inputs and a length and makes a randomized password, the problem however, is nothing is coming out. "line 29, in 
password = password + password_char
KeyboardInterrupt"
i had to stop it myself because it wouldnt output or stop itself after even a few minutes

```
Uppercase = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
Lowercase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
Numbers = "0123456789"
Symbols = "!@#$%^&*"

length = int(input("how long would you like your password? : "))
amount = int(input("how many passwords would you like? : "))
Possible_chars = ""
Q_Uppercase = input("Would you like uppercase characters in your password? : ").lower()
if Q_Uppercase == "yes":
    Possible_chars += Uppercase
Q_Lowercase = input("Would you like lowercase characters in your password? : ").lower()
if Q_Lowercase == "yes":
    Possible_chars += Lowercase
Q_Numbers = input("Would you like numbers in your password? : ").lower()
if Q_Numbers == "yes":
    Possible_chars += Numbers
Q_Symbols = input("Would you like symbols in your password? : ").lower()
if Q_Symbols == "yes":
    Possible_chars += Symbols

i = 0
while i < amount:
    password = ""
    while password != length:
        password_char = random.choice(Possible_chars)
        password = password + password_char
    print(password)
    i += 1
```

Comment: You mean `while len(password) != length:`, or `while len(password) < length:`. You're currently comparing the password itself against `length`. A string will never be equal to a number though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while i < amount:
    password = ""
    while len(password) != length:
        password_char = random.choice(Possible_chars)
        password = password + password_char
    print(password)
    i += 1
```